# Checkbox values not saved in form in Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, checkbox

I have a form which will not save the information users select through checkboxes.  I am guessing that I wrote the form_for incorrectly.  I have a user model which stores the checkbox list in an array.  I would greatly appreciate help in how to save the information users enter in checkboxes.  I have the set up as follows:

**_form.html**

```
 <%= form_for @user, html: {multipart:true} do |f| %>

 <%= render "shared/error_messages", object: f.object %>

<label for="user-amenities" class="top">Amenities</label>
    <ul class="group" id="user-amenities">
      <% User.amenities_list.each_with_index do |amenity, index| %>
        <li class="checkbox-li">
          <input type="checkbox" name="user_amenities_indicies[]" value="<%= index %>">
            <%= amenity %>
          </input>
        </li>
       </ul>
      <% end %>
```

**user.rb**

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    authenticates_with_sorcery!
    validate :amenities

def self.numerical_options
    ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16+"]
    end

  def self.amenities_list
    ["Smoking Allowed",
     "Pets Allowed",
     "TV",
     "Cable TV",
     "Internet",
     "Wireless Internet",
     "Air Conditioning",
     "Heating",
     "Elevator in Building",
     "Handicap Accessible",
     "Pool",
     "Kitchen",
     "Free parking on premise",
     "Doorman",
     "Gym",
     "Hot Tub",
     "Indoor Fireplace",
     "Buzzer/Wireless Intercom",
     "Breakfast",
     "Family/Kid Friendly",
     "Suitable for Events",
     "Washer",
     "Dryer"]
  end

  def self.integer_from_options_list(options_list)
    # convert options list given by radio buttons into one-hot integer
    amenities = 0;
    if options_list
      options_list.each do |option|
        amenities += 2 ** option.to_i
      end
  end

    amenities
  end

   def self.find_with_filters(filters)
    filtered_users = User
        if filters[:amenities]
          amenities = User.integer_from_options_list(filters[:amenities])
          filtered_users = filtered_users.where("amenities & ? = ?", amenities, amenities)
        end
    end


 def set_amenities_from_options_list!(options_list)
    self.amenities = User.integer_from_options_list(options_list)
  end

    def boolean_array_from_amenities_integer
    [].tap do |amenities_list|
      User.amenities_list.length.times do |order|
        amenities_list << (self.amenities & 2 ** order > 0)
        end
      end
    end

end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.set_amenities_from_options_list!(params[:user_amenities_indicies])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Thank you for signing up! A confirmation email has been sent to your inbox"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**views/users/index/_user_list.html.erb**

```
<ul class="group" id="users-index-list">

  <% @users ||= users %>

  <script type="application/json" id="bootstrap">
    <%= @users.to_json.html_safe %>
  </script>

  <%= render partial:"users/index/user", collection: @users %>
  <li><%= paginate @users %></li>

</ul>
```

**views/users/index/_user.html.erb**

```
<li class="group list-item">

  <a href=<%= user_url(user.id) %> class="user-image-wrapper">
    <%= image_tag(user.image_url(:thumb), class: "user-image user-image-small") %>
    <span class="map-number"><%= user_counter + 1 %></span>
  </a>

  <%= link_to image_tag(user.image_url(:thumb), class: "host-image user-image-thumb"), user_url(user.id), method: :get %>

  <header>
    <h3>
      <%= link_to user.first_name, user, method: :get%>
    </h3>

  </header>
```

In the console I get:

```
"user_amenities_indicies"=>["0", "1", "2"], "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"3"}
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Comment: Connection refused? That would kind of explain the inability to save to the database - can you explain this issue?

Comment: I have a partial which I render for new users and for editing account information. It is a quite extensive _form.html which I have in short form above, the extended version has fields such as; f.text_field :first_name, f.text_field :city etc.
The last part of the form I have included is the portion above with the user amenities. however when I click on the checkboxes and click save, everything is saved except the amenities checkboxes.  In the console it says Connection refused - connect(2)