# proper syntax for a form_for in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, save

I am trying to write a form for an array

```
<%= form_for @user, html: {multipart:true} do |f| %>

 <%= render "shared/error_messages", object: f.object %>

<label for="user-amenities" class="top">Amenities</label>
    <ul class="group" id="user-amenities">
      <% User.amenities_list.each_with_index do |amenity, index| %>
        <li class="checkbox-li">
          <input type="checkbox" name="user_amenities_indicies[]" value="<%= index %>">
            <%= amenity %>
          </input>
        </li>
       </ul>
      <% end %>
```

However I am not utilizing the |f| and it is not saving the options in the amenities_indices.  Any idea on how to refactor this code to utilize the f so the user information can be saved?

Answer (score 1):

Try simple_form https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/README.md

What you're looking for is :collection and then :as

Answer (score 0):

**Code Block**

The refactoring you seek is basically that you need to use the `f.` with all your inputs

Reason being that if you call [`form_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for), it essentially means you're calling a huge code block, in which every `attribute` needs to be bound to your form object, in order to render with your params hash correctly

In short - your `form_for` renders an HTML form, keeping the names of the `<input>` elements in line with the requirement of your application to load the `params`. The problem you have is that omitting the `f.` call will keep those `inputs` *outside* the scope for your params, leading to the issue you're seeing.

--

**Save**

If you don't have any associative data (which I've described below), you'll want to include your inputs in the `f.` code block:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <% User.amenities_list.each_with_index do |amenity, index| %>
      <%= f.check_box :user_amenities_indicies, index %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will pass the checked values of the `user_amenities_indicies` checkboxes through to your controller. This *should* work, and is the correct syntax for you

--

**fields_for**

A further addition is that I don't know whether you're trying to populate `associative` data or not here - but if you were trying to create data for another model, you'll want to use [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for):

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def new 
      @user = User.new
      @user.user_amenities.build
   end 

   def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)
      @user.save
   end

   private

   def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:user, :params, user_amenities_attributes: [])
   end
end
```

This will allow you to create a form using `fields_for`, like this:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :user_amenities do |ua| %>
       # fields for user_amenities
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Rick, I greatly appreciate it! I tried your solution under save but got 'NoMethodError in Users#edit undefined method `merge' for 0:Fixnum' with ' <%= f.check_box :user_amenities_indicies, index %>' highlighted. My full problem is here if you want to take a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987176/checkbox-values-not-saved-in-form-in-ruby-on-rails-application

Comment: Thanks - let me take a look!!